# Punctuation after such as

Tags: punctuation

What type of punctuation do you use after such as?

I see that sometimes it is used with a colon but I looked at grammar rules and colons are only used when listing things that cannot be immediately followed. 
For example you wouldn't write this (according to the website):

> I want: butter, sugar, and flour.

So why would you write (this is from yahoo answers so it may be wrong. If so please tell me):

> List your activities, such as: clubs, volunteering, and paid work.

Also when do you add commas after such as?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is just giving an example, you don't need any punctuation 
For instance, List your activities such as clubs, volunteering and paid work.

However, you need a comma in from if such as is part of the non-restrictive clauses.

For instance, Fresh fruit provides many nutrients, such as vitamin C, and tastes good too.

you can see the explanation in [grammerly](https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/comma/38/such-as-comma/) too.

There shouldn't be any punctuation after such as.